# Parallelizing a Python for-loop that plays two players against each other (game theory simulation)

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, game-theory

I'm writing a game theory simulation in Python. As part of the simulation, each generation, two players are paired and played against each other (each player is an instance of the `Player1` or `Player2` classes). Simplified a bit, the code looks like this:

```
pool1 = [Player1() for _ in range(50)]
pool2 = [Player2() for _ in range(50)]

assignments = range(50)
random.shuffle(assignments)

pairs = []
for i, assignment in enumerate(assignments):
    pairs.append((pool1[i], pool2[assignment]))

for player1, player2 in pairs:
    repeat = True
    while repeat:
        repeat = play_game(player1, player2)
```

Payoffs are kept as an attribute of the player. At the end of each round, depending on the moves of the players, the game will either continue or end (`play_game` will return True or False respectively).

How can I make this code run in parallel? That is, how can I play more than 1 pair play each other at once? I've Googled around a bit and found the Python [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) library, but I can't figure out how to apply it to this snippet of code.

Thanks!

Comment: multithreading and multiprocessing are very different beasts, so you should decide which one you want first.

Comment: I know very little about both. From my searching around, it seems like multiprocessing is easier to work with, right?

Comment: Without knowing what's happening in your play game function it's hard to say what to do exactly. How is output being handled in play game? How many cores to do you have available? A naive solution would be to fork a process for each pair. That would result in 50 processes. Depending on what's happening in play_game() that could be fine or it could swamp your CPU. Need more information.

Comment: The strategies are represented as finite state automata. In play_game() the two strategies are played against each other (the first player's move is fed into player 2, who responds by deciding whether to continue playing or stop). Payoffs are added after each move. It's pretty light weight, not a ton of computation involved in that step. I'm planning on running this on an EC2 instance. Probably 4-8 cores ("vCPUs").

Comment: @sundance well generally `threading` is easier to work with since you don't have to worry about interprocess communication (something you might want to research).  But in CPython, `threading` is subject to the Global Interpreter Lock (more research) meaning that it will *not* result in performance speedups if your task is CPU-bound - in fact it will result in slowdowns.  `multiprocessing` sidesteps that limitation but can have additional complications that `threading` won't have.

Comment: I've tried implementing the above snippet with `multiprocessing.Pool`'s `map` function, and it runs about two times *slower* (when initializing with no argument for number of pools, and when initializing with 3 pools (my computer has 4 cores)). Is there some other kind of multiprocessing/multithreading that would be more suited to speeding up this code. It seems obvious that this would run faster in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a class `Game` that is inherited from `threading.Thread`, so it behaves similar to the thread. `Game` class constructor accepts two player objects and `number` of the game.

`number` is required to facilitate returning of the game result into main program through the shared variable `resultList` (lists are thread-safe in Python). `resultList` is a list of lists and each `Game` instance puts the result to the corresponding cell of `resultList` according to its `number`.

`run()` method of each `Game()` instance is executed in a different thread so all the games are going on in parallel.

```
import threading
numOfGames = 10
resultList = [[] for x in xrange(numOfGames)]

class Game(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, player1, player2, number):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.number = number
        self.player1 = player1
        self.player2 = player2

    def run(self):

        #Your game algorithm between self.player1 and self.player2 is here

        #Put game result into shared list
        resultList[self.number] = <result>
```

To work with the `Game` class you do the following:

```
#Create instances of the Game() class, pass your Player() objects
#You can do the step in loop
game0 = Game(<PlayerObj>,<PlayerObj>,0)
game1 = Game(<PlayerObj>,<PlayerObj>,1)

#Start execution of Game.run() methods of all Game() objects in separate threads
#You can do the step in loop
game0.start()
game1.start()

#Wait until all Game.run() methods are executed = all threads are finished
#You can do the step in loop
game0.join()
game1.join()

#In the shared list you have corresponding return values, 
#whatever they are in your case [[result of Game 0],[result of Game 1],[]...]
print resultList
```

**PS:** I wouldn't recommend to go with multiprocessing since there is a substantial overhead in creating a process (need to allocate stack etc.). In your case multiprocessing would suffice since your application has no need in memory isolation.

Comment: The "result" returned by playing the game is actually stored in the player objects themselves (payoffs, an attribute of each player, holds that value). So, I don't actually need the results of the game in any list. Does that simplify things at all?

Comment: Sure, no problem here. Your `Player` objects will retain the state they have after all the games. `Player` object variables are modified in Game.Run() but keep the value once all the threads are joined. 'resultList' becomes unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Just to comment on the comments on your post (don't have enough rep for a comment), it was likely slower because of the overhead induced by creating so many processes.  Unless play_game is going to be CPU intensive or otherwise long running, you probably don't want separate processes for that.  Threads are generally less intensive to start (more true on Windows than Unix/Linux, since Unix/Linux treats threads as processes), and are probably closer to what you need.

Part of the problem is your use of result.  It looks like play_game can return False and kill the loop, however this model will not work with threads since they will not be executed in a linear manner anymore.  If you just want to run all of them, you could change

```
for player1, player2 in pairs:
    repeat = True
    while repeat:
        repeat = play_game(player1, player2)
```

to

```
thread_list = []
for player1, player2 in pairs:
    thread_list.append(threading.Thread(target=play_game,args=(player1,player2)))
for wait_thread in thread_list:
    wait_thread.join()
```

to start threads for all of those different pairings at once.  If you want to be able to kill off all of the running threads if one of them does not return True you're going to need to look at communication between threads, and you'll need to have a listener thread in your main program to read the output of the threads while they run.

Comment: Thanks for the info. As I commented in the other answer just now, the "result" returned by playing the game is actually stored in the player objects themselves (payoffs, an attribute of each player, holds that value). So, I don't actually need the results of the game in any list. Does that mean I could just run `threading.Thread` without appending to a list?

Comment: Yes, you could.  The reason I append them to a list, and then do the join() is to force the application to wait until all of the games are done before it moves on.  I assume that whatever you are doing is going to operate on those objects after the game, and if you do not wait for all of the threads to complete or otherwise ensure that the object you are working on is from a finished thread you will end up with race conditions.